# Serializing a Tree into Json Object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, tree

I have the following classes:

**TreeNode.cs**

```
public class TreeNode : IEnumerable<TreeNode>
{
    public readonly Dictionary<string, TreeNode> _children = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();

    public readonly string Id;
    public TreeNode Parent { get; private set; }

    public TreeNode(string id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public TreeNode GetChild(string id)
    {
        return this._childs[id];
    }

    public void Add(TreeNode item)
    {
        if (item.Parent != null)
        {
            item.Parent._childs.Remove(item.Id);
        }

        item.Parent = this;
        this._childs.Add(item.Id, item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<TreeNode> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._childs.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this._childs.Count; }
    }
}
```

**FolderStructureNode.cs**

```
public class FolderStructureNode : TreeNode
{
    //Some properties such as FolderName, RelativePath etc.
}
```

So, when I have an object of type `FolderStructureNode` it is essentially a tree datastructure where each node represents a folder.
I want to serialize this object into a JsonObject. I have tried both - JavaScriptSerializer and NewtonSoft. In both cases I get an output as -

```
[
  [
    []
  ],
  [
    []
  ],
  []
]
```

At the time of serialization, the tree looks something like this:

[image: Tree]

How do I serialize it in order to get the correct json object? Do I have to traverse the tree and create the json myself?

Comment: I think the serializer looks at the object's properties so try wrap the _childs dictionary in a property instead.

Comment: The problem is that your `TreeNode` class implements `IEnumerable<TreeNode>` so the serializer will serialize your node as an array (which is empty in your case). I can't tell why it's empty without seeing your `IEnumerable` implementation code.

Comment: I have added the entire TreeNode class.

Comment: @Christian: Sorry, that did not help.

Comment: I just wrote an working answer about this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275335/convert-a-treeview-to-json-using-c-sharp/54845249#54845249

Comment: I answerd this question on the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275335/convert-a-treeview-to-json-using-c-sharp/54845249#54845249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, your `TreeNode` class is serialized as an array because it implements `IEnumerable<TreeNode>`. So the only thing you will ever see when a `TreeNode` is serialized, are the children of a node. These children are (of course) also serialized as an array - down to the last leaf node. The leaf nodes don't have children and are therefore serialized as empty arrays. So that's why your JSON output looks like this.

You didn't exactly specify what JSON output you want to have, but I think what you want is like this:

```
{
    "Sales Order": { },
    "RFP":
    {
        "2169": { }
    },
    "Purchase Order":
    {
        "2216": { }
    }
}
```

To achieve this, your `TreeNode` class must be serialized as *object*. In my opinion (and assuming/suggesting you're using Newtonsoft Json.NET), you should write a custom converter class which might look like this:

```
class TreeNodeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // we can serialize everything that is a TreeNode
        return typeof(TreeNode).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // we currently support only writing of JSON
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // we serialize a node by just serializing the _children dictionary
        var node = value as TreeNode;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, node._children);
    }
}
```

Then you have to decorate your `TreeNode` class with the `JsonConverterAttribute` so the serializer knows that it has to use your converter when serializing a `TreeNode` object.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(TreeNodeConverter))]
public class TreeNode : IEnumerable<TreeNode>
{
    // ...
}
```

If you don't use Json.NET, I can't exactly tell you what to do but it might help if you would implement `IDictionary` instead of `IEnumerable` so the serializer knows you're dealing with key-value-pairs.

Comment: I simply removed IEnumerable, because it wasn't really required.. It worked now.. Thanks a lot! Although, I didn't understand why the objects inside the arrays weren't getting serialized.

Comment: They did get serialized. But they were serialized as an array containing the child nodes, which are also serialized as array and so on. So you won't get anything but arrays. The last children (leaf nodes) don't contain any children, so they're serialized as empty array. They can't be serialized as anything else (like the ID) because they *must* be arrays, too.

Comment: Works fine write! But how do you implement ReadJson?

Answer (score 0):

I was preparing data from database for [bootstrap treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview). And this worked for me:

```
public class TreeNode {
    public string id { get; private set; }

    public string text { get; private set; }

    public bool selectable { get; private set; }

    public readonly Dictionary<string, TreeNode> nodes = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();

    [JsonIgnore]
    public TreeNode Parent { get; private set; }

    public TreeNode(
        string id,
        string text,
        bool selectable
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.selectable = selectable;
    }

    public TreeNode GetChild(string id) {
        var child = this.nodes[id];
        return child;
    }

    public void Add(TreeNode item) {
        if(item.nodes != null) {
            item.nodes.Remove(item.id);
        }

        item.Parent = this;
        this.nodes.Add(item.id, item);
    }
}
```

Buildng tree:

```
var mapping = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

foreach(var ln in mx) {
    // 
    var ID = (string)ln[0];
    var TEXT = (string)(ln[1]);
    var PARENT_ID = (string)(ln[2]);

    // 
    var node = new TreeNode(ID, TEXT, true);

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PARENT_ID) && mapping.ContainsKey(PARENT_ID)) {
        var parent = mapping[PARENT_ID];
        parent.Add(node);
    }
    else {
        tree.Add(node);
    }
    mapping.Add(ID, node);
}

var setting = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
};

// Ignore root element, just childs - tree.nodes.Values
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tree.nodes.Values, setting);

// Empty dictionary - remove (not needed for valid JSON)
return json.ToString().Replace("\"nodes\": {},", "");
```