# How to convert from WPF TreeView to JSON

Tags: c#, json, wpf, treeview

I have the following JSON structure

```
{
    "test1.1": {
        "test2.2": {},
        "test2.3": {},
        "test2.4": {
            "test3.1": {},
            "test3.2": {},
            "test3.3": {}
        },
        "test2.5": {
            "test4.1": {},
            "test4.2": {},
            "test4.3": {}
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm able to display it in a TreeView in WPF:

[image]

now I want to convert the TreeView back into the same JSON structure/file.

This is my approach so far but having trouble getting to the exact same

```
    private string ConvertTreeViewToJson(TreeView treeView)
    {
        List<object> treeViewItems = new List<object>();
        foreach (TreeViewItem item in treeView.Items)
        {
            treeViewItems.Add(Recursion(item));
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(treeViewItems, Formatting.Indented);
    }

    private object Recursion(TreeViewItem item)
    {
        var node = new List<object>() {item.Header};

        if (item.HasItems)
        {
            List<object> children = new List<object>();
            foreach (TreeViewItem childItem in item.Items)
            {
                children.Add(Recursion(childItem));
            }
            node.Add(children);
        }

        return node;
    }
```

this is the return:

```
[["test1.1",[["test2.2"],["test2.3"],["test2.4",[["test3.1"],["test3.2"],["test3.3"]]],["test2.5",[["test4.1"],["test4.2"],["test4.3"]]]]]]
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41503997/6292693) answer your question?

Comment: How did you originally deserialize your JSON before loading into your `TreeView`?

Comment: This is an odd data structure. You have basically an object with properties that are named "test1.1", "test2.2" etc. and each property has another object with named properties as value. But a "real" tree data structure is composed of node objects that have child nodes. Each node can have attributes. But the point is that a node has a children and a parent. This means, your JSON must be formed using arrays of objects (nodes). This data structure is quite easy to handle.

Comment: It looks like you got JSON wrong and/or the data tree. Do not use nested properties but use a parent child relationship (tree data structure). You can't traverse a nested property structure. But you can conveniently traverse a parent-child structure. I suggest to fix your data structure first. Then take alook at the System.Text.Json namespace: [JSON serialization and deserialization (marshalling and unmarshalling) in .NET - overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/overview)

Comment: The point is, even if your structure were reasonable, you can't deserialize such an object to a C# object, unless you have a static structure (static in number of properties and property names). In this case you would have to hardcode a C# object that has N properties named "test1.1" etc. This doesn't make sense IMO. I assume you want to have a dynamic JSON structure where nodes can be added/removed and names of the nodes can change.

Comment: @BionicCode I generally agree with all of your comments. However, it's not true that you can't deserialize OP's object into C#, you can achieve this with [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-8.0) (or Dynamic). Also consider the particular case of the type TreeViewItem. It seems it has its [own template mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) to structure the data in a meaningful way, and it can possibly be used also when serializing/deserializing.

Comment: @BionicCode In fact, there's other posts around (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296318/6292693) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275335/convert-a-treeview-to-json-using-c-sharp)) where people serialize and deserialize TreeNode structures (similar to TreeView) in JSON without any problem.

Comment: @jarmanso7 It is not possible to directly deserialize that kind of structure. You have to manually convert it to an equivalent C# object. When using dynamic you lose all the strong typing and compiler support to produce robust code. This is not JS. Why would you want that? Instead, one should create a proper tree structure. Nesting properties, is just that.

Comment: @jarmanso7 The TreeViewItem you mention is itself an ItemsCintrol. This way, the TreeView is able to display a proper data tree - dynamically and with anonymous data models. Because each TreeViewItem can have an arbitrary number is children by adding more TreeViewItems to the TreeViewItem.ItemsSource off a patent TreeViewItem. A proper tree structure is composed of objects (nodes) that have 0 or more children. Such a structure is dynamically de-/serializable wirkt and problems (gracefully). I know that it is possible. But it's going to be ugly.

Comment: @jarmanso7 The TreeView can't even handle such structure. You would have to convert it to a real tree structure anyways. To avoid all the overhead and brittle code I suggest to fix the JSON. It currently like it was created without deeper understanding if the intention was to create a data tree.

Comment: May I am about your goal? Did you design the JSON to create a tree structure or is it just a simplification of nested objects that you want to display as a tree?

Comment: Remember that a simple JSON object is a collection of key/value pairs, for example, a C# Dictionary. There are no lists (arrays) involved in your current JSON structure.It would be interesting to see how you deserislize this kind of JSON that sisters to have a random object depth snd random property names (key names).

Comment: the example I provided is just a simplification of what tree I have. And it has to be dynamically created, I cannot have any data objects in C# because the JSON changes completly from one example to another.

Comment: also note: what I provided you is just the first part of the application. After loading and visualizing the tree (as seen in the screenshot) I'm going to add childs with key:value pairs into this JSON e.g. "test2.2": {
      "Min": "1",
      "Max": "2"
    },

Comment: @BionicCode I agree

Comment: @HannesH. you should provide all the necessary information in your question, the earlier the better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the answer I originally linked under your question in a comment, I figured out a solution. In order for JsonConvert to return key-value pairs instead of arrays, you should use a `Dictionary<string,object>` instead of a `List<object>`.

The Key string of each entry will store the header value of a `TreeViewItem`, and the Value of that same entry will store a nested Dictionary with all the corresponding `TreeViewItems`:

```
private string ConvertTreeViewToJson(TreeView treeView)
{
    var treeViewItems = new Dictionary<object,object>();

    foreach (TreeViewItem item in treeView.Items)
    {
        treeViewItems.Add(item.Header.ToString(), Recursion(item));
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(treeViewItems, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
}

private Dictionary<string, object> Recursion(TreeViewItem item)
{
    if (item.HasItems)
    {
        var children = new Dictionary<string,object>();

        foreach (TreeViewItem childItem in item.Items)
        {
            var grandChildren = Recursion(childItem);

            children.Add(childItem.Header.ToString(), grandChildren);
        }
        return children;
    }

    return new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

Comment: In a real world application your won't handle the UI containers. Instead, you would handle data models. You should create a data model for the TreeView and then convert to/from a data model that reflects the JSON object. Or de-/serialze directly between the two different structures by implementing a converter/ manual serialization (depending on the used library). Doing it your way is prone for trouble.

Comment: that might be a good start if I have additional code which detects if there is a valid key:value property and adds it accordingly

Comment: @HannesH. I agree with BionicCode. It makes more sense to serialize/deserialize the data bound to your views rather than the objects responsible for presenting the data to the user. How are you populating your TreeView with data in the first place?